# php-reading xml child node value

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, xml-namespaces

Trying to get the node value of `ds:X509Certificate` in PHP. I am able to navigate till `IDPSSODescriptor` tag, any pointers on how to access child node values.

```
<EntityDescriptor>
      <IDPSSODescriptor>
        <ds:Signature >
             <ds:SignedInfo>..</ds:SignedInfo>
             <ds:SignatureValue>..</ds:SignatureValue>
              <ds:KeyInfo>
                 <ds:X509Data>
                   <ds:X509Certificate/>
                 </ds:X509Data>
               </ds:KeyInfo>
         <test>
         <test2>
      </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

php code working so far,

```
$data = $idp_xml->IDPSSODescriptor->attributes()->ID;
```

I tried,

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($idp_xml->IDPSSODescriptor);
$data = (string) $xml->ds:Signature[0]->ds:KeyInfo->ds:X509Data->ds:X509Certificate.
```

Comment: Hi just read your request but xml file does not seemed to be well formed can you supply more details of your xml files

Comment: Error in your XML, `ds` is a `namespace-prefix`, and it is not defined in your snippet, see http://www.xmlvalidation.com This is probably the reason why you cannot access it.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

```
$childNode = $idp_xml->IDPSSODescriptor->children();
```